# Display progress during save() in R?

Tags: r

Suppose the data objects are quite large and the saving takes a while, is there someway to display the progress of the save() function in R? How about showing that in the UI in Shiny?

Comment: I've used https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/progress/index.html

Comment: A shiny method https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html

Comment: Don't these methods require iteration or looping to show progress? If one is just saving a big file with a single "save()" command, can the progress still be shown?